# Loading .dll with ctypes

Tags: python, c, gcc, dll, linker

I have a .dll with dependencies to some other (Sundials ODE solver) .dlls. I use windows 8.1 with mingw to compile and link the c-code I use for my .dll. When trying to load them with Python and ctypes I get a pop-up with a `System error: cannot find libsundials_cvode.dll since it does not exist on the computer` and when you close the popup Python spits out `WindowsError: [Error 126] Cannot find the module` Cannot understand why this is, because gcc compiles and links the files fine without errors (and yes, they do exist)... I have even tried to copy the dependent dlls into the directory where my python script is, without success.

I run the following compile and linker commands without any warnings or errors

```
gcc -c -I c:\sundials\include cfile.c
gcc -shared -o clib.dll cfile.o -L. C:\sundials\instdir\lib\libsundials_cvode.dll -L. C:\sundials\instdir\lib\libsundials_nserial.dll
```

My python test script giving the abovementioned error is

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('clib.dll')
```

I'm a beginner with gcc and c, but quite experienced with Python. Any suggestions what might be the reason?

Comment: What happen if you add `C:\sundials\instdir\lib` to your PATH?

Comment: This seems to work like a charm! Great Anto, thanks for the answer. If you post it as a seperate answer I will accept it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Wikipedia [Dynamic-link library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library):

*"...Unless your DLL is a Component Object Model (COM) server, the DLL file must be placed in one of the directories listed in the PATH environment variable, in the default system directory, or in the same directory as the program using it..."*

So, add `C:\sundials\instdir\lib` to your PATH env. variable.